# jquery issue on chrome and safari: working fine in FF and IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, pagination

below is the link of a page where i use pagination script using jQuery which is working fine on IE and FF. but not working on chrome and Safari any idea ?

http://www.hosturway.com/test/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=3

Answer (score 0):

developer tools on chrome says so : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) nav-sep.png`

you might want to check that first before selling that yummy looking pizzas :)